# Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty} xf(x) = L$

Tags: real-analysis

**Question**:

Let $f: (a,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} xf(x) = L$ where $L\in \mathbb{R} $. 
Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$.

**Attempt**:

I see that in order for $\lim_{x\to\infty} xf(x) = L$, either $f(x)$ must be bounded and strictly decreasing or $x \to 0$ for the limit to be $L$. Ruling out the latter because that's not what I'm trying to prove, I looked at a bounded monotone decreasing $f(x)$.

Splitting the limit into two:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} xf(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) * \lim_{x\to\infty} x = L$

The second term in the middle goes to infinity as $x \to \infty $, which means that to counteract the $\infty$, the $f(x)$ must decreasing faster than linearly and must go to zero.

I'm wondering if this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: What if $L=0$??

Comment: I did it for any arbitrary $L$. If I began with $L=0$ then one can immediately say that one proved it...

Comment: You may not split the limit of products into to products of limits. This is only allowed if the two limits do exist, which you don't know here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to assume that $f$ is monotone decreasing, consider for example $f(x)=(\sin x/x)^2$ for $x\geqslant1$, which is neither decreasing nor increasing.

To prove the result, note that, if $xf(x)$ has a limit when $x\to+\infty$ then $xf(x)$ is bounded for $x$ large enough. Let us assume only that $xf(x)$ is bounded for $x$ large enough, that is, that there exists $C$ and $x_0$ such that $|xf(x)|\leqslant C$ for every $x\geqslant x_0$.

Then $-C/x\leqslant f(x)\leqslant C/x$ for every $x\geqslant x_0$ and both the LHS and the RHS converge to $0$. By the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), $f(x)\to0$ when $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: Aha, I didn't think about or even try some $f(x)'s$ could be so quickly assumed monotone decreasing. Thank you for the great use of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem!

Comment: Bolzano-Weierstrass? What are you talking about?

Comment: Only the squeeze theorem is used as I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists some $M>1$ such that if $x \ge M$, then $|L-x f(x)|  < \frac{1}{2}\epsilon$.

Dividing across by $x$ gives $|\frac{L}{x} - f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2x} \le \frac{1}{2} \epsilon$.

We have $|f(x)| \le |\frac{L}{x} - f(x)| + |\frac{L}{x}|$. Now if $x \ge M' = \max(M, \frac{2|L|}{\epsilon}+1)$ we have $|f(x)| < \epsilon$.

Hence $f(x) \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$Proof.$ Let $f:(a, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} xf(x) = L$ where $L \in \mathbb{R}$, we will show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.  $\forall\ \varepsilon > 0.$ Choose $K = (|L| + 1)/ \varepsilon$. $\forall\ x > K$ Since $xf(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, $$|xf(x) - L| < 1\ $$ i.e. $$|xf(x)| \le |L| + 1$$
So $$|f(x) - 0| = \left| \frac{xf(x)}{x} \right| \le \frac{|L|+1}{|x|} < \frac{|L|+1}{K} = \frac{|L|+1}{(|L| + 1)/ \varepsilon} = \varepsilon.$$ Therefore $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0.$